# Передать POST запрос

Tags: javascript, post

Можно ли POST запрос сделать к нескольким страницам одновременно?

Есть форма, которая уже передает значения через `action` на внутренние файлы. Там происходят какие то проверки. И в конечном счете открывается страница `complete.php`. Я не хочу перебирать 1000 строк кода, чтобы искать, что откуда там передается и по какой цепочке.

Можно ли сделать (может на JS) параллельный POST значения 1-го `input` этой формы, чтобы когда мы все таки попали на `complete.php` можно было бы считать значение интересующего нас поля формы через `echo $_POST ['input.value'];`?

Comment: А что там перебирать? форма сабмитится либо  кнопкой, либо любым ивентом начинающимся с 'on' в теле открывающего тега либо через id хендлер. Вам придётся перебирать код.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener-%D0%B8-removeeventlistener